# Android - Check any dialog is displayed on the screen and get the dialog instance

Tags: dialog, instance

I have a requirement that I need to check if there is any Dialog displayed on the screen from the non activity class(library project). If the dialog is displaying on the screen Then I need to dismiss the dialog.

I have an activity instance stored in the library project. How can I check any dialog is displayed over the activity with out storing the dialog instance in the activity.

Please let me know if there is any way to do this.

Comment: Please help me if there is any to do this.

Answer (score -2):

Dialog has an isShowing() method that should return if the dialog is currently visible. So you can use that to see if a dialog is showing and hide it with dismissDialog(). You just have to keep a reference to the Dialogs you create in onCreateDialog().